# How to convert char array to uint8 array in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
arr1 = ["h","e","l","l","o"] as! Any

for i in 0..<arr1.count
{
    let newString:String = arr1[i] as! String

    let data1:UInt8 = UInt8(newString)!

    arr[i] = data1
}
```

Comment: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: What is the expected result? And what would it be  for `arr1 = ["€","",""]` ?

Comment: i have array [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] as [UInt8] and replace arr1 to first 5 object of array. EX: [h, e, l, l, o, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. arr1 type is nsmutableArray.

Comment: It is still unclear to me. Please *update the question* with a clear description of input and expected output.

Comment: arr =  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Please [**edit your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44645756/edit) and add all relevant information.

Comment: Sorry, i dont know how to explain this type of question, so please help me for proper question title.

Comment: var arr = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 20); //[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0].       i need to replace first 5 object from arr to [h, e, l, l, o,] as uint8

Answer (score 3):

It can be achieved through `String` representation of `Character` to convert in `UInt8`
You can use `String.UTF8View`, is a collection type, Now you can easily convert in to `UInt8` using `map`. as

```
let charArray: [Character] = ["h","e","l","l","o"]
let arrayUInt8 = String(charArray).utf8.map { (val) -> UInt8 in
    return val
}

print(charArray)
//["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]

print(arrayUInt8)
//[104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
```

Comment: Or `Array(String(chars).utf8)`

Comment: charArray = NSMutableArray();  so how to convert charArray as character or string?

Comment: @DeepakTagadiya you have a string convert in to UInt8 or charactes?

if you have string than can use like let arrayUInt8 = "hello".utf8.map { (val) -> UInt8 in
        return val
    }

or charArray then like above

Comment: convert into UInt8, but charArray = NSMutableArray(); so all objects type is Any.

Comment: when you are grtting your charArray type cast while storing it, using if let or gaurd let

Comment: How to remove "<>" from "<34b453a67d>"?

Answer (score 2):

It does not really make sense to convert an array of characters to `UInt8` because some characters cannot be represented by just 8 bits, like ""

This is how you would convert characters to `[UInt32]` though:

```
let chars: [Character] = ["a", "", "c"]
let result = chars.map { UnicodeScalar($0.description)?.value }.filter{ $0 != nil }
```

Or, you can use this method to convert chars to `UInt8`, but filtering out those that can't be represented in 8 bits:

```
let chars: [Character] = ["a", "", "c"]
let result = chars.map { UnicodeScalar($0.description) }.filter { $0 != nil && $0!.isASCII }.map { UInt8($0!.value) }
```

Comment: This crashes for `""`

Comment: @MartinR I assume the OP doesn't intend to handle anything non-ASCII. I kinda fixed it anyway.

Comment: How to remove "<>" from "<34b453a67d>"?

Comment: @DC2313 `dropFirst` and `dropLast`

Comment: i got solution: data= [val[n],...,val[3], val[2], val[1]]

Comment: @Sweeper how to convert byte array to int?

Comment: ex: val = [byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4]